# cv2.setMouseCallback conflict with cv2.waitKey: not capturing keyboard events after handling mouse events

Tags: python, opencv

I'm working on a Python application using OpenCV to capture both mouse and keyboard events. I've set up event handlers for both mouse clicks and keyboard presses. However, I'm encountering an issue where keyboard events are not registered after handling a mouse click event.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = np.ones((100, 100, 3))
def plot_image():
    cv2.imshow('Image', image)
def click_event(event, x, y, flags, param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        print(f'left click')

plot_image()

cv2.setMouseCallback('Image', click_event)

while True:
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    if key == 83:  # right arrow
        print('right')

    elif key == 81:  # left arrow
        print('left')

    elif key == 27:  # esc
        print('esc')
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

In this code, before a mouse click the key handling seems to work as expected. However once the a mouse click event is handled, keyboard events (arrow key presses) are not registered.

How can I modify my code to ensure that both mouse and keyboard events are captured without interference?

Thanks!

Comment: Cannot reproduce, works as expected. (The "left arrow" and "right arrow" don't, since those codes correspond to letters Q and S, but that's a different issue it seems)

Comment: Thanks @DanMašek - can I ask what version of opencv are you using? I should have said that I'm running on red hat linux and using opencv-python  4.8.1.78

Comment: On Windows, multiple versions of OpenCV. [edit] your question and add that information to it. The GUI backend might be what's making a difference here. I assume yours is GTK? Add that info as well.